# There is no package named "CLACK.APP.DIRECTORY"

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am learning about Common Lisp and the [Clack](http://clacklisp.org/), following the tutorial:

http://clacklisp.org/tutorial/06-using-clack-app-directory.html

But in this chapter(Using Clack.App.Directory) I can't success, the SLIME prompts error: "There is no package named "CLACK.APP.DIRECTORY" "

But I followed all the steps in the tutorial, is there anything I missed? I am noob in lisp BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The codebase changed much since version 1, and the tutorial is a little bit outdated. There is, however, a compatibility layer to that version.

```
(ql:quickload :clack-v1-compat)
```

Then, the appropriate packages are loaded and you should be able to continue the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, it can run now, but the page shows "not found" even my path is correct. Do you have any idea where the newest tutorial is?

Comment: @SoulClinic The latest development about Clack is here: https://github.com/fukamachi/lack. There is no tutorial yet for version 2, but the readme in the previous link has some details.